# Spring security change permitAll list of URLs at runtime

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I need to change spring security configuration at runtime for my use-case where I need to maintain an XML that contains vanity urls and corresponding urls. So I need to tell spring at runtime about the urls that are newly added to XML and not to block the access to those public urls.

My start up configuration looks like this.

```
public static String[] PERMIT_ALL_URLS = new String[] { "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/healthcheck.jsp", "/healthCheck",
        "/healthcheck.xml", "/memberLogin.html", "/login.html","/wro/**","/*home.html", "/home.html","/auctions.html","/*auctions.html", "/upgrade-subscription", "/pages/**","/public/**", "/", "/Content/**","/CMS/Content/**","/saleListResultAllFrame/**"};

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    List<String> permitAllUrls = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(PERMIT_ALL_URLS));
    if (configDataManager.getAllRedirectUrlsMap() != null)
    {
        permitAllUrls.addAll(configDataManager.getAllRedirectUrlsMap().keySet());
    }
    String[] publicURLPatterns = permitAllUrls.toArray(new String[permitAllUrls.size()]);
    _logger.info("Loading Spring Security Configurations - Public URLS - " + publicURLPatterns);
    copartAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/doLogin.html");
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(copartAuthenticationEntryPoint);
    http.csrf().disable().headers().disable().sessionManagement().sessionFixation().none();

    http.addFilterAfter(new RestTimoutRedirectFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(copartPreAuthenticationFilter, AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(memberSiteCodeFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(memberSiteCodeFilter, AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
            .anonymous().authenticationFilter(new CopartAnonymousAuthenticationFilter());

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(loginUrl).access("isAnonymous() or isAuthenticated()")
            .antMatchers(publicURLPatterns).permitAll().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
            .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl(loginUrl).loginPage(loginPage).permitAll().usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password").successHandler(copartAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureUrl("/doLogin.html?result=error&error=authFailure").permitAll().and().logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/doLogout.html?result=success")
            .deleteCookies(Constants.AUCTION_COOKIE).permitAll();
    http.portMapper().http(HTTP_PORT).mapsTo(HTTPS_PORT).http(HTTP_PORT1).mapsTo(HTTPS_PORT1);
}
```

I need a way to reconfigure spring security every time the vanity url xml changes.